# Starting multiple services in the background in python over remote server

Tags: python, background, subprocess, popen

Summary: I have to start various services from the command line by a script which runs on a remote server, which creates subprocesses for each of the services and stores the PID in some form.

I am not able to make each process run in the background by this script of mine. Except the first 2, that is es and redis, the others run in the foreground and do not give the terminal back for the next command to execute.

Where am I going wrong?
Here is the script:

```
import os
import sys
import commands
from var import key_loc
import subprocess
import pipes
import shlex

def check(status):
    if status != 0:
        print 'Error! '
        quit()
    else:
        print 'Success :) '
    file1=open('/home/modiuser/status.txt','a')
    file1.write("Success :)\n") 

if(sys.argv[1]=="ES"):
    os.chdir('/home/modiuser/elasticsearch-0.90.0/bin/')
    #proc1=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("nohup ./elasticsearch -p /home/modiuser/es.pid"))
    os.system('nohup ./elasticsearch -p /home/modiuser/es.pid > /dev/null 2>&1 &')
if(sys.argv[1]=="REDIS"):
    os.chdir('/home/modiuser/redis-2.6.13/src')
    #proc2=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("./redis_ss -p /home/modiuser/redis.pid"))
    os.system('nohup ./redis_ss -p /home/modiuser/redis.pid > /dev/null 2>&1 &')
if(sys.argv[1]=="PARSER"):
    proc3=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("nohup java -jar logstash-1.1.12-flatjar.jar agent -f parser.conf"))
    file1=open('/home/modiuser/pid.txt','a')
    file1.write("PARSER-"+str(proc3.pid)+"\n")
    file1.close()
    os.wait(proc3.pid)
if(sys.argv[1]=="SHIPPER_TCP"):
    proc4=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("nohup java -jar logstash-1.1.12-flatjar.jar agent -f shipper_TCP.conf"))
    file1=open('/home/modiuser/pid.txt','a')
    file1.write("SHIPPER_TCP-"+str(proc4.pid)+"\n")
    file1.close()
if(sys.argv[1]=="SHIPPER"):
    proc5=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("nohup java -jar logstash-1.1.12-flatjar.jar agent -f shipper_test.conf"))
    file1=open('/home/modiuser/pid.txt','a')
    file1.write("SHIPPER-"+str(proc5.pid)+"\n")
    file1.close()
```

Comment: just a hint, did you try fabric, which is a tool in Python crafted for remote automation via ssh?

Comment: consider configuring your services to be run by a supervisor such as `upstart`, `runit`, [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/index.html) and use corresponding commands to start services e.g., `sv up shipper` (the latter command can be easily run by [fabric](http://fabfile.org) on remote hosts)